# Why does the map in my controller always returns a nullpointerexception?

Tags: java

Controller.java

```
Map<String, String[]> formData  = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();

    if(formData.get("firstName") != null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not null");

    }
```

When I click the save button after I run the program, it always returns an error message of `NullPointerException` even if I put a value in the firstName textbox.

Comment: I read your question as "Here is some random code that may or may not be related to the error message that I'm not going to give you."

Comment: may be you need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements

Comment: The code above is my code in trying to get the value of a textbox via the map. The error I get everytime is NullPointerException.

Comment: Wherever you read `NullPointerException`, there would have been a mention of exact line number too, where this error is occurring. What is it?

Comment: @rD. It points at this line -  if(formData.get("firstName") != null) {

Answer (score 1):

There is some good information in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) on how to detect and resolve null pointer exceptions. In your case it is likely that on of your object references is null. Check if `request()` or `request().body()` or `formData` is null. An easy way to do this is to add `assert` statements before you use the reference. It's also possible that the error is unrelated to the code you have included in your question.

To pinpoint the location of the error, use the [stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) or have your debugger take you to the line of code that causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's important that to validate for

1. Whether your map is `null` or not
2. Whether your map contains `"firstName"` key
3. Whether the value for `"firstName"` is empty or not.

Please note that these validations should be in exact order as mentioned above.

You can change your code to:

```
Map<String, String[]> formData  = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();

if(formData!= null && formData.containsKey("firstName") && !formData.get("firstName").equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not null");
}
```